# ListAdapter filter in Android

Tags: android, filter, android-listview, listadapter, textwatcher

I have problem with listview filter in my app. In KartyListFragment.java I declared:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ctx,
    R.layout.karty_list_item, db.getKarty(), from, to, 0);
```

now in StartActivity.java in OnCreate method I have EditText and TextWatcher.

```
EditText searchInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

    watcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            KartyListFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s); //THIS ROW IS WRONG
            //it doesn't know getFilter() 

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    };

    searchInput.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

in OnTextChanged method I need call getFilter() method of adapter but it write error. I read a few tutorials. There are used ArrayAdapters and I'm using List (Cursor). Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Change your adapter from `ListAdapter` to a `CursorAdapter`. A `ListAdapter` doesn't implement the 'getFilter` method. By the way, you'll need to implement a [QueryFilterProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FilterQueryProvider.html) to run your query on the background and do the actual filtering of the list.

Comment: excellently, thanks. but now there is error "no enclosing instance of the type is accessible in scope" in OnTextChanged method (KartyListFragment.this. is underline)

Comment: Make sure your `adapter` is an instance variable instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ListAdapter` to `SimpleAdapter`

These's work for me :) `SimpleAdapter` have `getFilter` method